# Duplicate keys in Merged Map ignored

Tags: java, merge, hashmap, java-stream

I've been trying to understand why the duplicate key function is not triggered when collecting the map, with no luck. I'm using Java SE 8 [1.8.0_141].

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Long, Long> ts1 = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
    Map<Long, Long> ts2 = new HashMap<Long, Long>();

    ts1.put(0L, 2L);
    ts1.put(1L, 7L);
    ts2.put(2L, 2L);
    ts2.put(2L, 3L);


    Map<Long, Long> mergedMap = Stream.of(ts1, ts2)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (v1, v2) -> { 
                            System.out.println("Duplicate found");
                            return v1 + v2;}
                    ));

    mergedMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()));

}
```

The result is

```
    0 2
    1 7
    2 3
```

I'm expecting

```
    0 2
    1 7
    2 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
ts2.put(2L, 2L);
ts2.put(2L, 3L);
```

The 2nd `put` is overwriting the first one. So the `ts2` map only contains one entry: the last one: `(2L, 3L)`.

So then, there's nothing to merge.

Comment: My bad, I must be tired :) Thanks for your answer